# Changing the default width of a search box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap and currently need to change the width of a search box. I also want to give it a space as it's in a container but the search box and button are touching the picture above and my nav bar below and it doesn't look good. I used `&nbsp` for patching it but it leaves a huge gap that really isn't good. Here is my CSS & HTML. The JS file and CSS file are both the default files downloaded from bootstrap itself. Any pointers would help

```css
.form-inline .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.form-inline .form-control-plaintext {
  display: inline-block
}

.form-inline .input-group {
  width: auto
}

.form-inline .form-check {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 0
}

.form-inline .form-check-input {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: .25rem;
  margin-left: 0
}

.form-inline .custom-control {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.form-inline .custom-control-label {
  margin-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Search -->
<form class="form-inline ">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 " type="search" placeholder="I'M LOOKING FOR..." aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-pnpsample my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<!-- End search -->
```

Comment: You should post a **complete** code snippet, not just the form. After all your issues go beyond just the form.

Comment: @WebDevBooster yeah I noticed my mistake just now, as I explained it to Mikkel the search was wrapped in 3 columns where search is in the 2nd one so I just adjusted the columns and it worked. Thanks for the advice, will give more detail next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
HTML

```
<div class="searchcont">
    <form class="form-inline ">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 " type="search" placeholder="I'M LOOKING FOR..." aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-pnpsample my-2 my-sm-0 " type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.searchcont{margin-top: 50px;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank for the margin that helped and I completely forgot about setting the margin(noob mistake)

Comment: @Kira You'r wellcome, [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a bigger width to the form element.

```
form {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Regarding the whitespace between the image I can't really help you there as you would need to include more of your markup to be able to see whats going on.

Comment: I discovered my mistake, the form is wrapped in 3 columns, where search is in the middle, I adjusted my col parameters and it worked but thank you for that snippet I kept it in my js file encase I need it later for something else